# Almacenar la info de un combox en una variable en C#

Tags: c#, combobox

Apenas comienzo en el tema de la programación, y quiero solicitarles su ayuda; tengo un inconvenientes y es que no encuentro como almacenar en una variable los valores de un combobox en C#.

Tengo un combobox que lo he llamado CmbMes. en este almaceno los números de los mes (1,2,3...12).

al momento de ir a la parte del codigo tengo dispuesta una variable mes de tipo int y es ahí donde quiero almacenar el combo pero me sale error.

He intentado con mes= CmbMes.text; , con mes= CmbMes.SelectedValue; , y un par más y no me funciona.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Es Winforms? WPF?

Comment: es en Windows forms

Comment: Lo que quieres es obtener el elemento seleccionado del combobox? Si es así puedes utilizar el evento "SelectedIndexChanged" del mismo combobox, cada vez que el usuario selecciona un elemento del combo se lanza ese evento. Si al combobox le asignas loa numeros puedes "castear" la propiedad selecteditem cuando ocurra el evento, pero primero verificas que la propiedad SelectedIndex sea mayor o igual a cero, porque si SelectedIndex es menor que cero quiere decir que no hay ningún elemento seleccionado.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que las propiedaddes para obtener el valor seleccionado del combobox es de tipo Object o String y tu variable es entera, por tanto tienes que convertirlo.

Ejemplo:

```
int n = int.Parse(comboBox1.Text);
//o
int n = int.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

No se como estas llenando tu `ComboBox` pero aqui te muestro un ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo.

```
private void llenarComboMeses(ComboBox combo)
{
     List<string> lista_meses = new List<string>();
     lista_meses.Add("Enero");
     lista_meses.Add("Febrero");
     lista_meses.Add("Marzo");
     lista_meses.Add("Abril");
     lista_meses.Add("Mayo");
     lista_meses.Add("Junio");
     lista_meses.Add("Julio");
     lista_meses.Add("Agosto");
     lista_meses.Add("Septiembre");
     lista_meses.Add("Octubre");
     lista_meses.Add("Noviembre");
     lista_meses.Add("Diciembre");

     //Limbiar los datos del combo, para no duplicarlos al volver a generarlos
     combo.DataSource = null;
     combo.Items.Clear();

     //Recorrer la lista y asignar los valores al combo
     foreach (string mes in lista_meses)
     {
        //Asignando los valores.
        combo.Items.Add(mes);
     } 
 }
```

Para utilizar la función así:

```
llenarComboMeses(CmbMes);
```

Luego para obtener el valor del mes selecionado puedes hacerlo en el evento `SelectedIndexChanged` de tu `ComboBox` asi:

```
private void CmbMes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (CmbMes.SelectedIndex >= 0)
     {
        //Asignar el valor a tu variable.
        mes =  CmbMes.SelectedIndex + 1;
     }
}
```

> Se hace esto: `CmbMes.SelectedIndex + 1;` sumando 1 porque el indice comienza en cero por lo tanto al sumar uno el indice 1 será igual a `Enero` , luego indice 2 = `Febrero`, etc...